# Алгоритм получения разницы между двумя числами Javascript

Tags: javascript

Как проверить разницу между числовыми переменными в Javascript? Вопрос, вроде, элементарный, но соображений почему-то нет. Объясню, что конкретно нужно.

Если числа `10` и `20`, то разница равна `10`.

Если числа `-5` и `3`, то разница равна `8`.

Если числа `-13` и `-15`, то разница равна `2`.

Подскажите алгоритм функции, которой если я дам два числа, то мне вернётся разница между ними.

Comment: Алгортм: взять разницу между числами: `a – b` и лишить результат знака.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Серьёзно?

```js
function get(a, b){
  return Math.abs(a - b);
}

console.info(get(10, 20));   // 10
console.info(get(-5, 3));    // 8
console.info(get(-13, -15)); // 2
```

Comment: почему вы назвали функцию «get»?

Comment: @Sergiks, первое, что пришло в голову. Просили алгоритм, а не креативное название.

Comment: Самое сложное в программировании - нейминг и инвалидация кэша. Остальное - ерунда.

Comment: Собственно `Math.abs(a - b) ` и есть функция - нафига ее во что то заворачивать?

Comment: @DenisMatafonov, много букаф, да и это метод, если придираться до конца :)

Answer (score 4):

```
function range(a, b){
   return Math.abs(a-b);
}
```